# How to trigger Child re-rendering with dummy prop

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I haven't found an article on how to do this so I'd like to know in the case where I change a child's main object it uses in it's parent but this happens in a way that none of it's methods are triggered what is the recommended way to trigger a re-render?

My approach is to just pass a dummy prop which provokes a trigger of the "onComponentWillReceiveProps" method in which I compared it's passed prop to props and thus detect a change has occurred which will in the end trigger the re-render of this component (the child).

This isn't broken or anything I just thought I kinda hacked it together and wanted to know if there was a clean, recommended, "React way" to this.

thanks

UPDATE : I actually thought this would work but my hack doesn't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hacking it into `onComponentWillReceiveProps` you can use the designated lifecycle method [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). There you can check your current props, the next props to be delivered and compare them.

Comment: Great answer but just to be sure we agree : you are saying still in that case pass a "dummy" parameter a parameter with no relevant info (in my case a new uuid) in order to communicate with shouldComponentUpdate just for the sake of a re-render and nothing else?

Comment: or are you saying that I can actually in the parent's DOM tag for the child put : `<Child shouldComponentUpdate={() => ()} />` . And then I don't need to change anything in the child or maybe just put that method and that's it?
(I should have specified I'm something of a beginner)

Comment: @tatsu If the UUID changes then you can compare it with the latest prop and do the re-render.

Comment: well it turns out that didn't work either x'D I'll need a full parent + child code spinet to understand

Comment: This approach feels wrong. The purpose of `shouldComponentUpdate` is to allow an optimisation in case a change in props doesn't need a re-render, you can return false. The default is that it will return true (if it isn't there), so that's probably why your attempts are failing. The most reliable way to trigger a render is to set the state, so you should work out where to do this.